# how do I peek inside tgz file in bash?

Tags: bash, archive, tar, gzip, peek

how do I peek inside tgz file in bash?

I have this

```
$ ls -la /tmp/*.tgz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bitnami bitnami 2832 Jun 28 15:33 /tmp/name_1.tgz
$
```

Comment: How about `tar -tf filename.tgz`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tar tf /tmp/name_1.tgz
```

t lists the contents. See the manpage.